# Problems with testset and trainset being too similar

Tags: r, linear-regression, overfitting-underfitting

In the dataset I have been given, the independent variables are given in intervals of 50 as shown below.

[image]

Hence, when I perform a train-test split on the dataset for linear regression, I obtain very similar train sets and test sets as shown:

[image]

I believe that this has an effect that is equivalent to training on the test set, which gives misleading results. Is it right to say, the test set may obtain high predictive accuracy, but my model will not be able to detect overfitting since overfitting is often detected through a large difference between train set and test set?

Additionally, what kind of limitations will having similar train and test sets pose in my modelling?

Comment: You might take a look at this source: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-strategically-accomplish-your-machine-learning-models-performance-goals-44dddc11697e/                     I don't think there is a huge problem now, but you might want to create a holdout set or use other metrics besides the accuracy.

Comment: This question probably belongs to [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), however another option could be add some fake data on train, using functions like `step_upsample()` or `step_bsmote()`.